# data transfer from php to javascript using json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

I am building a Google maps page that uses lat long data coordinates to create a heat map to show the proliferation of foxes in an area.

As it currently stands, my app works fine when the lat long values are hard coded into my JavaScript function `get_points` on my index.php like this.

> index.php (NB: This code works if tested but requires a google maps api key to load map and heatmap points)

```
<?php require_once("resources/config.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Heatmaps</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <style>
     /* NOTE - GOOGLE MAPS NEED HTTPS (SECURE ORIGIN) OR IT WILL NOT SHOW A MAP. IT WILL CATEGORICALLY NOT WORK ON HTTP*/
     #map {
       /*height: 425px;*/
       height: 100%; 
     }
     /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
     html, body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
     #floating-panel {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 10px;
       /*left: 25%;*/
       z-index: 5;
       background-color: #fff;
       padding: 5px;
       border: 1px solid #999;
       text-align: center;
       font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
       line-height: 30px;
       padding-left: 10px;
     }
     #floating-panel {
       background-color: #fff;
       border: 1px solid #999;
       /*left: 25%;*/
       left: 6%;
       padding: 5px;
       position: absolute;
       /*top: 10px;*/
       z-index: 5;
     }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<!--NOTE - GOOGLE MAPS NEED HTTPS (SECURE ORIGIN) OR IT WILL NOT SHOW A MAP. -->
   <div id="floating-panel">
     <button onclick="changeRadius()">Danger Radius</button>
   </div>
   <div id="map">
    <!--Google map is renderedhere-->
   </div>
   <script>
     function showPosition(){
         if(navigator.geolocation){
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initMap, showError);
         } else{
             alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
         }
     }

     var map, heatmap;

     function initMap(position) {
       lat = position.coords.latitude;
       long = position.coords.longitude;

       var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long); 
       var myOptions = {
           center: latlong,
           zoom: 16,
           mapTypeControl: true,
           navigationControlOptions: {style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
       }

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlong, map:map, title:"You are here!"});
       heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
         data: getPoints(), //
         map: map
       });
     }

     // Define callback function for failed attempt
           function showError(error){
               if(error.code == 1){
                   result.innerHTML = "You've decided not to share your position, but it's OK. We won't ask you again.";
               } else if(error.code == 2){
                   result.innerHTML = "The network is down or the positioning service can't be reached.";
               } else if(error.code == 3){
                   result.innerHTML = "The attempt timed out before it could get the location data.";
               } else{
                   result.innerHTML = "Geolocation failed due to unknown error.";
               }
           }

     function changeGradient() {
       var gradient = [
         'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
         'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
         'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
         'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
         'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
         'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
         'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
       ]
       heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
     }

     function changeRadius() {
       heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
     }

     function changeOpacity() {
       heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.4);
     }

     function getPoints() {
       return [
         //////////////////// I DONT WANT TO HAVE TO HARD CODE THESE VALUES ///////////////////////////////////////////

         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179, -4.415), 

         // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256),
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256),
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.910083, -4.403256),

         // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91088, -4.40407), 
         ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403390), 

         // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099),
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099),
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91055, -4.404099), 
 // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648),
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067, -4.403648), 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       ];
     }
   </script>

   <script async defer
       src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY=visualization&callback=showPosition">
   </script>

   <!--javascript and jquery CDN's directly beneath here-->
   <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, I don't want to hardcode the lat long coordinates in my `get_points()` function.

I am having bother serving these lat long points from my `MySQL` table to the said function using a php function I designed which uses json_encode.

I am getting errors mainly saying "not a valid MVC array". Yet strangely,  I can print the array out.

> My Table Schema

[db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekyzw.png)

> My Custom PHP function

```
function get_coordinates() {
        $coordinates = array(); // initial decleration of memory 
        $latitudes = array(); // see above
        $longitudes = array(); // see above

        // Select all the rows in the location_values table
        $hotpointquery = query("SELECT `locationLatitude`, `locationLongitude` FROM `location_values` ");
        confirm($hotpointquery);

        while ($row = fetch_array($hotpointquery)) {
            $latitudes[] = $row['locationLatitude'];
            $longitudes[] = $row['locationLongitude'];

            // instantiate new map php array which is a COMBINATION of $latitudes and $longitudes and google map object. 
            $coordinates[] = 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $row['locationLatitude'] .','. $row['locationLongitude'] .'),';  

            //convert the PHP array into JSON format, so it works with javascript
            $json_array = json_encode($coordinates);
        }

        //this block removes comma in very last lat lang element in our db
        $lastcount = count($coordinates)-1; // dorman : counts all lat lang in the databse n-1;
        $coordinates[$lastcount] = trim($coordinates[$lastcount], ",");  // for each pair, use trim function to remove the white space and comma in the last element of our lat lang at end of db

        // echo print_r($coordinates[$lastcount]); // this only prints out one set of lat langs
} // end of function/////////////
```

> new_get_points()

```
function getPoints() {
  var array = <?php echo $json_array;?>
}
```

Comment: *"I am getting errors mainly saying "not a valid MVC array". Yet strangely, I can print the array out. "* Where do you get this error i assume in Javascript and you see it in the web developer tools?

Comment: in the console.... under the errors tab

Comment: Did you try to Google the error or track down the error in the Google Javascript file so you know which code part is responsable pretty sure that gives clues about the formatting?

Comment: I think its more of an issue of how I am passing the information over from my php function to the javascript function called get_points or I am not pulling it proper from within such

Comment: Maybe hard to tell without all the Javascript code...

Comment: Annyhow [Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps (Google docs link)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps) .. Also keep in mind that you can generate XML in a MySQL query as well with CONCAT()/GROUP_CONCAT() ticks.

Comment: `var array = …` – the `var` keyword makes this a local variable inside the `getPoints` function, so unless you _return_ it from there to the outside, it stays inside that function and doesn’t get seen by anything else.

Comment: I understand that I've tried it with the return as well

Comment: Are you still getting this error? Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @evan I have not managed to figure this out.

Comment: I see, let me have a look at this.

Comment: Okay so just to rule this out before I look deeper into your code implementation, note that the script you've posted is not correct, i.e. `key=APIKEY=visualization` should be `key=APIKEY&libraries=visualization`. I assume this is just a mistake in your posted code and is not the actual script you're using in your app?

Comment: Yes that is correct. At my end the API key  uses &libraries=visualization

Comment: I was hiding my API key there and inadvertently chopped that off.

Comment: No problem just wanted to ensure this wasn't the actual issue. Okay so your HTML/JS code works on my end too, but I've still yet to test your PHP code which is where the issue likely lies. When you say you're able to print the array, is it in fact an array of strings? does it look like this? `["new google.maps.LatLng(55.922179,-4.415)","new google.maps.LatLng(55.91067,-4.403648)"]` Because if so, that wouldn't work. It needs to be an array of LatLng objects.

Comment: Yes that's how the array prints

Comment: Well then we've identified the root cause. Use latlng objects (with the given lat lng values retrieved from your db) in your array, not strings. This will fix your issue.

Comment: Can you doctor my code with the solution please so I can see it

Comment: Appreciated.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a *data exchange format*, not a programming language. When you include something like "new google.maps.LatLng..." in a string, that's all it is: a string. It doesn't mean anything – and even if it did, your PHP code isn't returning anything, and your JavaScript code isn't executing anything.

You are sort of on the right track though, so let's make some small changes.

In your PHP, you can do this:

```
<?php

function get_coordinates() {
    $hotpointquery = query("SELECT `locationLatitude`, `locationLongitude` FROM `location_values` ");
    confirm($hotpointquery);
    while ($row = fetch_array($hotpointquery)) {
        $coordinates = [$row['locationLatitude'], $row['locationLongitude']];
    }
    return json_encode($coordinates);
}
```

Later in the page, within the `<script>` element you can have PHP print out that array, then JS can manipulate it into the objects you're looking for using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
function getPoints() {
   var coords = <?= get_coordinates() ?>
   var points = coords.map(function(coord) {
       return new google.maps.LatLng(coord[0], coord[1]);
    });
    return points;
}
```

Comment: I will try both when we return to the station later and revert back. Thank you

Comment: Evans that init map function is poorly formatted with the ... And the [...] I cannot make any sense of that

Comment: @miken32 appreciate your steering but that code does not work either. The entire map fails to load when I refactor my functions like that. I suspect the line of code you have that says var coords = <? get_coordinates() I don't think you can assign a full PHP function to a JavaScript var like this

Comment: Of course you can @stackrookie or I wouldn’t have suggested it. Did you look at the resulting code from it? Did you check console for errors? This is basic debugging stuff.

Comment: Their is a whole plethora of in promise errors. Cannot read property 0 of underdefined